# Mac High Sierra not able to open MacMail, iCal for more than 5 seconds

Tags: mail.app, email, ical

I am facing some issue with iCal and Mail Application. As soon I open it closes it self within 5 seconds.

http://g.recordit.co/8q6iIK6cFS.gif

I have tried following things

**Delete Following files**

- com.apple.mail.plist
- com.apple.mail-shared.plist
- /Users/users/Library/Mail/V4/MailData/Envelope*

**Reset NVRAM**

**Start in Safe Mode**

However nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your clock is displaying the correct local time, resetting NVRAM won't affect Mail or Calendar. I'd suggest being more aggressive in cleaning out of Mail's database files and then re-testing:

1. delete Mail.app's (~/Library/Mail/) data folder (not just its contents)
2. re-delete both /Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist & ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist
3. re-delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist (if it was re-created)
4. re-test

Answer (score 0):

**Start by resetting your NVRAM**

**How-To Reset NVRAM**

1. Choose Apple Menu > Shut Down
2. Power up your Mac
3. Immediately press these keys at the same time: Option, Command, P,
   and R and maintain this hold as your Mac boots
4. You must press the keys before the black screen with the Apple logo
   appears
5. Continue pressing the keys until your Mac restarts, around 15
   seconds Release the keys

**If Mail Keep on Crashing**

1. If you have an instance of the Mail app running on your macOS High
   Sierra, exit out it. If the app is unresponsive or frozen,
   force-quit the app
2. The next step is to address the Mail app’s preference files and
   remove them in the case they are corrupted and are causing these
   issues. Using your Finder app, much like before, choose Go and ‘Go
   to Folder…’ and type in the path as shown here and below in the
   image: `~/Library/Preferences`

[image]

3. Locate these two files: `com.apple.mail.plist` and
   `com.apple.mail-shared.plist` If you can’t locate these files, make
   sure you are looking at your User Library, not the Main Directory
   Library
4. Delete the two plist files by moving them to trash If you don’t want
   to delete these files, move them to your desktop to isolate them
5. Restart Your MacBook and then launch Mail and see if the issue has
   resolved If the problem is gone, go ahead and delete any files you
   isolated to the desktop