# Mac High Sierra not able to Set Touch ID - Canceled by another authentication

Tags: keychain, touch-id

I am not able to set the touch id, may be after some minor update to High Sierra. Before that everything was working fine.

I tried reseting the password for KeyChain Login and KeyChain Local items, however nothing is helping.

Keep on getting following error message.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a Keychain error and you probably need to rebuild it. These steps should fix it.

1. Open Finder.
2. Hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and on the menu click `Go`.
3. Click on `Library` to open that in Finder.
4. Drag the Keychain folder to the trash.
5. Restart your machine.

**You will have to re-enter all your passwords again** but it should fix the Touch ID.

Comment: that resolved my issue.

Comment: if you don't mind can you look at my other question regrading mac. 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342884/mac-high-sierra-not-able-to-open-macmail-ical-for-more-than-5-seconds

Comment: Did you try the answer already provided on that other question?

Comment: yes, I have tried all the things, nothing is working so far.

Comment: Not working for me as well

Comment: It appears I got most of my passwords and other Keychain artifacts restored (after trashing my `$HOME/Library/Keychains` (macOS = 10.14.6) folder, possibly if not probably due Keychain was originally synced to iCloud... and thus restored from iCloud?

Comment: Wasn't able to login anymore after I did this ...

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me was a restart. After the restart it requested me to enter the old password to 'update the password' for the keychain

I've been able to register a new fingerprint and to login using it ever since

Answer (score 1):

With macOS Monterey, in addition to [fsb](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342894/234688) steps:

1. Open Finder.
2. Hold the <kbd>Opt</kbd> key and on the menu click **Go**.
3. Click on **Library** to open that in Finder.
4. Open `Keychain` folder.
5. Remove all `login.keychain-db`, `user.kb`, and `keychain-2.db` files (mostly the ones recently modified).
6. Restart your machine.

With these steps, I was able to register a new fingerprint without losing all my previously saved login/passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't seem to work for me at first, but then later it did. Here are some other things I did, in case anyone else encounters the same issue. I'll start with what I think were more likely the case.

- I tend not to delete things. I renamed the *Keychains* directory to *Keychains.bak*. Maybe the system was still able to find this directory.
- I went to Keychain Access > Preferences > Reset My Default Keychains. It was a little wonky, like not letting me change the password to the **login** keychain (despite its instructions to do so), but after this step and following the accepted solution (deleting the *Keychains* directory), things worked for me.
- Before any of that I tried updating each of the keychain passwords in Keychain Access. I was surprised to find that the current password on the **Local Items** keychain was a password from a very old system that was on High Sierra. I had just restored a Mojave backup onto a Catalina system, but from the same drive that had a backup of that High Sierra system, so maybe some keychains got carried over that way.
- I had `csrutil disable`'ed in recovery mode to allow CDock to make changes to the system and forgot to enable it until later.

Again, I don't think the latter ones were relevant, but posting everything just in case.