# Touch ID Canceled by another authentication

Tags: keychain, catalina, touch-id

I've had this issue over multiple iterations of OS. This began for me in High Sierra, followed into Mojave, and now into Catalina. I finally figured I'd deal with it. I've tried everything I've found currently, and nothing works.

I've done the following.

1. Deleted everything in my Keychain folder and rebooted.
2. Deleted the entire /Library/Keychain folder itself, and rebooted.
3. Tested another profile, which did work, however it doesn't help me aside from knowing something's messed up with my profile.

Any other ideas before I blow this profile away? This is a work laptop so it'll be a pain to get this back to normal working order.

Comment: Already answered here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342894/304549

Answer (score 0):

From the link posted by @Sachin Sharma:

> The Touch ID problem is related to Keychain. Open Finder. Click Go once so the dropdown menu appears. Hold down the Option key. You will see a Library folder appear in the list under the Go tab. Open library. Drag Keychains folder into the trash [and restart machine]. You will have to re-enter all keychain passwords, but the Touch ID will work.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion might sound redundant but see if below link helps. I went through same steps and it worked for me. I am also on Catalina.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7765052

Comment: Pleas provide the answer her. Links do disappear